# Front End Module Translation changes not reflected in prestashop

Tags: internationalization, prestashop-1.6

We have created an small test module for Prestashop version 1.6.0.8. Everything is working good, but we are facing little issue with translation in front end. When we make changes in existing existing translation file like default English then no changes reflects on front end.

Same case occurs for new language. When we add new language then we are also facing the same issue.

For Example:
We have an module title which will be displaying on front and have two installed language; English(default) and french. If we change the title meaning in any both of the file then there is no change reflected on front.

Our translation file structure is:

```
modules/modulename/translations/en.php  
modules/modulename/translations/fr.php
```

Syntax to define title variable in translation file is:

```
$_MODULE['<{modulename}theme-name>modulename_md5_of_variable'] = 'My Module title'
```

In Front ent .tpl file, we have this variable as:

```
{l s='My Module title' mod='modulename'}
```

We have searched lot of things but nothing got. Kindly help me to know, is there any mistake  in above syntax or there is any other way to access this variable on front?

Solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Put your translation files in following path:
Dont forgot to clear your cache..
themes/{your-theme-name}/modulename/translations/en.php
themes/{your-theme-name}/modulename/translations/fr.php